# Detecting some mobile devices

Tags: iphone, mobile, screen, viewport, detect

What is a mobile device?

Are tablets considered to be mobile devices?

I want to detect some mobiles devices -- those that fall in the small screen range like iPhone, Android phones, iPod, etc. I do not want to check for tablets, like iPad, Kindle, etc.

My website has a mobile version that is designed to work on mobile devices like iPhone, etc.

I got this Coldfusion code from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/. However, I believe it checks for all mobile devices. Most of the devices I am not aware of.

Can someone help me with this code, to check for small screen mobile devices only?

```
<!--- Test for Mobile device --->
<cfif 
reFindNoCase("(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry
|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo
|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket
|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)
|xda|xiino",CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT) GT 0 
OR 
reFindNoCase("1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)
|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m
|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi
|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica
|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)
|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit
|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)
|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris
|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)
|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)
|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)
|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)
|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)
|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g
|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/
|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-
|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )
|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo
|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)
|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )
|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-",
Left(CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT,4)) GT 0>

    <!--- Javascript to switch Div's for Mobile --->
    <cfset MobileFound = true>
</cfif>
```

In addition to checking for the presence of a mobile device, I also check the screen width. But, due to the complexity of the website layout, I use jQuery to switch content between two DIVs for the mobile version.

This is the code I use for screen width:

```
<cfif MobileFound eq true>
    <meta 
        name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.5, 
        user-scalable=yes" 
    />
    <link 
        href=".../wBCCmobile.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css" 
        media="only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:480px)" 
    />
</cfif>
```

Comment: Base on the code above, ColdFusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted http://detectmobilebrowsers.com and they assured me that their code only detects [small] mobile devices and not tablets.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which language you are using?

If you are using php so you can try with below code.

```
if( strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android') ||
strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'webOS') ||
strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') ||
strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad') ||
strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
{
?>
<link href="give your mobile style sheet link" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php
}
?>
```

I hope you will get a result.